# When is this login going to be locked out?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, authentication

In my organization, we are creating a login with sysadmin privileges (SQL Authentication). The password should not expire, so we unchecked "Enforce password expiration" option.

The issue is that the login is going to be locked out. My questions are:

- How can we avoid the lock out issue?
- In what situations is the login going to be locked out?

Comment: A number of failed logins. Usually 3.

Answer (score 0):

It will be locked out depending on your Windows Server password policy.  By default when you create a login `CHECK_POLICY = ON`, see [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

> "SQL Server 2005 can apply the same complexity and expiration policies
>   used in Windows Server 2003 to passwords used inside SQL Server."
>   from [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161959%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

If you want to avoid this you need to create a login with `CHECK_EXPIRATION = OFF` as well as `CHECK_POLICY = OFF`

example:

```
CREATE LOGIN user1 WITH PASSWORD=N'A_nice_COMPLEX_Pa$$w0rd',
CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
```